# How to use mapstructure tag as json tag?

Tags: go, tags

I'm introducing a package from a third party that has this `struct` with `mapstructure` tag.

I want the instance of this struct to be json with `mapstructure` specified value.What should I do?

I can add json tag, but in doing so,I modify package files,I think this is a bad way.

```golang
type ServiceConfig struct {
    // name of the service
    Name string `mapstructure:"name"`
    // set of endpoint definitions
    Endpoints string `mapstructure:"end_points"`
    // defafult timeout
    Timeout time.Duration `mapstructure:"timeout"`
}
```

I want to get:

```js
{"name":"sss", "end_points" :"xxx", "timeout" : "120"}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do what you want without modifying the `mapstructure` source, and it would probably get a little bit hairy if you want to specify options, such as `json`'s `omitempty`. However, you can simply add a second struct tag for this

```golang
type ServiceConfig struct {
    // name of the service
    Name string `mapstructure:"name" json:"name"`
    // set of endpoint definitions
    Endpoints string `mapstructure:"end_points" json:"end_points"`
    // defafult timeout
    Timeout time.Duration `mapstructure:"timeout" json:"timeout"`
}
```

From the documentation of `reflect`

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally
>   space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string
>   consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '),
>   quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using
>   U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

[Here's a simple example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mxjirRO8vJ5)

Comment: mapstructure seems to support omitempty per its documentation as of this writing.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to modify the package files, you can create another struct with the same field names, but with JSON tags, and copy:

```
type JSONServiceConfig struct {
    Name      string        `json:"name"`
    Endpoints string        `json:"end_points"`
    Timeout   time.Duration `json:"timeout"`
}
```

Then:

```
x := JSONServiceConfig(serviceConfig)
```